# How to create TLS certificate for azure vm?

Tags: azure, ssl, openssl, tls1.2, lets-encrypt

I have **3 VM** in **azure** . I would like to create **TLS** certificates for those VM . can we do like that ?

Is there any documentation which to create a certificates if yes can you please share

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify context so I will assume all possibilities,
ensure that you're familiar with bash scripting and openssl.

1. Globally trusted: e.g. external user from internet can connect to your VM through https protocol, use Let's Encrypt or buy an SSL certificate
2. For internal connection only, self-signed certificates to be shared among VMs

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 \
    -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout server.key \
    -out server.crt \
    -subj "/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=Global Security/OU=IT Department/CN=example.com"
cat server.crt
```

3. For internal connection only, a recommended use case is to use PKI to grant certificates for every VM that join the network

Example certificate signed by a CA

```
# Generate CA key and cert
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -key ca.key -days 3650 -out ca.crt \
-subj '/C=AA/ST=AA/L=AA/O=AA Ltd/OU=AA/CN=AA/emailAddress=aa@aa.com'

# Generate server key and CSR
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr \
-subj '/C=BB/ST=BB/L=BB/O=BB Ltd/OU=BB/CN=BB/emailAddress=bb@bb.com'

# Generate server cert signed by CA
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key \
  -CAcreateserial -CAserial serial -in server.csr -out server.crt
```